# Are primes of a certain polynomial form?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

As far as I know there is no polynomial function 
$f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb P$ with just prime number results, but how about polynomials $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that for every prime $p$ there is a $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $p=g(n)$? For the odd primes there is the trivial polynomial $g(n)=2n+1$, but besides from that?

Comment: No polynomial of degree greater than $1$ can have this property; their values thin out too quickly, and it would contradict eg the prime number theorem.

Comment: Do we assume that $g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$? In this case, such a polynomial $f$ would have to be irreducible. Then it is even impossible for $f$ to have a root modulo $p$ for every prime $p$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608997/348926).