# Irreducible polynomial divisible by all primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Does there exist an irreducible non-linear polynomial $P(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that for any prime number $q$ there exists $t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $q|P(t)$ ?

Also (dis)proving whether there exists such polynomial that satisfies the condition for all but finitely many prime numbers is of interest.

All I have reached at the moment has been the polynomial $P(x)=(x^2-3)(x^2-5)(x^2-15)$ which is clearly not irreducible but has no integer roots and satisfies the condition of the problem and I couldn't do much more.

Comment: Is this already answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608919/is-it-true-that-if-fx-has-a-linear-factor-over-mathbbf-p-for-every-prim ?

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, $P$ must be linear, already for all but finitely many primes.

See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150810/irreducible-polynomials-with-a-root-modulo-almost-all-primes